# Помогите, пожалуйста: не понимаю, нужно ли ставить тире после слов «как максимум»

Tags: пунктуация

Без этих краеугольных критериев работа медицинской сестры будет как минимум непродуктивной, как максимум – абсолютно бесполезной для пациентов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, в данном случае тире нужно.

Предварительно:  "как минимум не продуктивн**о**й" - будет какой?

Теперь по сути вопроса. Тире при такой конструкции фразы заменяет опущенное слово "будет". Поэтому оно необходимо.

> Такое распадение часто наблюдается при пропуске какого-нибудь члена
>   предложения (почему ставящееся в этом случае тире называется
>   эллиптическим), например:
>
> Пусторослеву за верную службу – чижовскую усадьбу, а Чижова – в Сибирь навечно.
>   А. Н. Толстой
>
> Мы села – в пепел, грады – в прах, в мечи – серпы и плуги.
>   Жуковский
>
> Мне все послушно, я же – ничему.

П-56 § 173.